# jboss 6 clustering issue

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing, jboss6.x

I have an old application developed in ejb2 and struts that has to be deployed to a jboss 6.1 instance. If I deploy the application to a single node, it works with no problems. But if I try to deploy this same app in a clustered environment, I get an error:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] (http-10.101.215.38-8443-4) An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing: java.lang.RuntimeException: Caught TimeoutException acquiring ownership of Gb6p4nliysUprY2lXQwTrA__
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSession.acquireSessionOwnership(ClusteredSession.java:603) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSession.access(ClusteredSession.java:566) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2566) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2316) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JvmRouteValve.checkJvmRoute(JvmRouteValve.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:85) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:62) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.jboss.ha.framework.server.lock.TimeoutException: Cannot acquire lock //localhost/myapp/Gb6p4nliysUprY2lXQwTrA__ from cluster
at     org.jboss.ha.framework.server.lock.SharedLocalYieldingClusterLockManager.lock(SharedLocalYieldingClusterLockManager.java:554) [:2.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.distributedcache.ispn.DistributedCacheManager.acquireSessionOwnership(DistributedCacheManager.java:448) [:1.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSession.acquireSessionOwnership(ClusteredSession.java:595) [:6.1.0.Final]
... 20 more
```

At first I started to think it was a cluster configuration, but if in the same environment I  deploy another app that is built using ejb3 and no struts the cluster works perfectly.

Is there any special config that needs to be done to the jboss cluster to make an ejb2 app work?

Thanks

Kelly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the same problem as in this thread. Probably enabling sticky sessions will help.

[Clustering + Session sharing lock acquisition errors](https://community.jboss.org/thread/162109)

Comment: I have seen the post, it did not help :(